# ListView уходит за пределы формы

Tags: wpf, xaml

Почему-то ListView уходит за пределы формы и ScrollBar не становится активным:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как можно поправить?
Если ставлю явную высоту, то все работает, но при ресайзе формы все выглядит не очень кошерно...

Вот разметка самой формы:

```
<Window x:Class="DictionaryCreator.UI.Windows.DictionaryConfigurationWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DictionaryCreator.UI.Windows"
        xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Конфигурация справочника" SizeToContent="Height" Width="1200">
    <Window.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Command="{Binding CancelCommand}" Key="Escape" />
    </Window.InputBindings>
    <Grid Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
        <Grid.Resources >
            <Style TargetType="Border" >
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5,5,5,5" />
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" ColumnSpan="2" DataContext="{Binding DictConfigVM}">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition ></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition ></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="ButtonWidth"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
                <Label  HorizontalContentAlignment="Right">Тип базы данных</Label>
            </Border>
            <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
                <ComboBox  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DbKinds}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedDbKind}"/>
            </Border>

            <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" >
                <Label HorizontalContentAlignment="Right">Сервер (MSSQL) или путь к файлу (MS ACCESS)</Label>
            </Border>
            <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
                <TextBox  Text="{Binding Path=FilePathOrServerName,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            </Border>

            <Border Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0">
                <Label   HorizontalContentAlignment="Right">Название базы данных</Label>
            </Border>
            <Border Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1">
                <TextBox  IsEnabled="{Binding Path=DbNameEnable}" Text="{Binding Path=DbName,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>
            </Border>

            <Border Grid.Row="3">
                <Label  HorizontalContentAlignment="Right">Название таблицы</Label>
            </Border>
            <Border Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1">
                <ComboBox  DockPanel.Dock="Left" MinWidth="350" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TableDescriptions}" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedTableDescription}">
                    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock>
                                <Run Text="{Binding Schema}" />
                                <Run Text="." />
                                <Run Text="{Binding TableName}" />
                            </TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ComboBox>
            </Border>

            <Border Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2">
                <Button  DockPanel.Dock="Right" Command="{Binding Path=RefreshTablesCommand}"  >
                    <Image Style="{StaticResource ImageIcon}"  Source="../Icons/Refresh.png"/>
                    <Button.ToolTip>
                        Обновить
                    </Button.ToolTip>
                </Button>
            </Border>

            <Border Grid.Row="4">
                <Label  HorizontalContentAlignment="Right">Ключ таблицы (целое число)</Label>
            </Border>
            <Border Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1">
                <TextBox   Text="{Binding Path=SelectedKeyColumnDescription.ColumnName,Mode=TwoWay}"
                           IsReadOnly="True" Focusable="False"/>
            </Border>
            <Border Grid.Row="5">
                <Label  HorizontalContentAlignment="Right">Название поля для нормализованного значения</Label>
            </Border>
            <Border Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1">
                <ComboBox  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ColumnDescriptions}" DisplayMemberPath="ColumnName" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedFullTextColumnDescription}"></ComboBox>
            </Border>

        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <!-- положим пустую колонку такого же размера как и сверху -->
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="ButtonWidth"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  Margin="0,0,-10,0">
                <GroupBox DataContext="{Binding AlgorithmConfigVM}">
                    <GroupBox.Header>
                        Настройка алгоритма
                    </GroupBox.Header>
                    <Border>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding NormalizeServices}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedNormalizeService}" DisplayMemberPath="NormalizeAlgorithmType.Name"/>

                            <Border>
                                <StackPanel >
                                    <Label>Параметры алгоритма</Label>
                                    <ListView MaxHeight="250"  ItemsSource="{Binding Params}">
                                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <Grid>
                                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                    <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding Item.Name}"></Label>
                                                    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Value}"></TextBox>
                                                </Grid>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                    </ListView>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Border>
                            <Border>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <Label>Настройка привязок результатов раскладки</Label>
                                    <ListView  ItemsSource="{Binding FieldBindings}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedBinding}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <Grid>
                                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                    <Label Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                                                        <TextBox IsReadOnly="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" BorderThickness="0" Focusable="False" Cursor="Arrow" >
                                                            <TextBox.Text>
                                                                <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} ({1})" Mode="OneWay">
                                                                    <Binding Path="Item.Name" />
                                                                    <Binding Path="Item.Description" />
                                                                </MultiBinding>
                                                            </TextBox.Text>
                                                        </TextBox>
                                                    </Label>
                                                    <ComboBox  Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=StackPanel},
                                        Path=DataContext.AvailableColumns}" DisplayMemberPath="ColumnName"
                                              SelectedItem="{Binding Value}">
                                                    </ComboBox>
                                                </Grid>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                    </ListView>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Border>

                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </GroupBox>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
        <WrapPanel Grid.Row="2"  Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0 30 0 25">
            <Button Command="{Binding Path=SaveCommand}" Margin="0 0 25 0">
                <Button.Content>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Style="{StaticResource ImageIconWithMargin}"  Source="../Icons/Save.png"/>
                        <Label VerticalAlignment="Center">Сохранить</Label>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button.Content>
            </Button>
            <Button Command="{Binding Path=CancelCommand}" Margin="0 0 25 0">
                <Button.Content>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Style="{StaticResource ImageIconWithMargin}"  Source="../Icons/Cancel.png"/>
                        <Label VerticalAlignment="Center">Отменить</Label>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button.Content>
            </Button>
        </WrapPanel>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

Comment: Оберните в ScrollViewer, места недостаточно, куда ему деваться ещё...

Comment: Разметка странноватая, зачем вам целая куча ненужных Border? Вертикальные StackPanel тоже выглядят ненужными. Я бы сделал все это просто в гриде по строкам. И почему вы продолжаете использовать Label? В WPF это абсолютно бессмысленный аналог ContentControl, для отображения простого текста надо брать обычный TextBlock, для отображения сложного контента — собственно ContentControl, Label не нужен никогда

Comment: @АндрейNOP Имеете ввиду ListView положить в ScrollViewer? Положил, но что-то так же все=(

Comment: Потому что у вас StackPanel, он выделяет контролу столько места, сколько тот хочет и не важно, что столько места физически нет. У вас на верхнем уровне грид с тремя строками, вот я бы весь контент второй строки обернул в ScrollViewer

Comment: Но для начала можете попробовать обернуть в ScrollViewer ваши StackPanel. Вообще в WPF для успеха надо хорошо понять и прочувствовать как себя ведут какие контейнеры, понять как происходит компоновка

Comment: @АндрейNOP если оборачивать StackPanel, то результата нет. Если обернуть весь Row, то работает, но Scroll стремно выглядит, так как находится за пределами GroupBox'а

Comment: Хорошо, тогда оберните не всю строку, а контент GroupBox'а. Ну и рекомендации выше по избавление от StackPanel в силе

Comment: @АндрейNOP Я выпилил стек панели и заменил на грид, а затем добавил скроллвивер внутрь групбокса, но все равно=(

Comment: @АндрейNOP А во... Я у грида auto на звездочку сменил и заработало